# How to make external libraries available as soon as they load with webpack

Tags: webpack

If you simple do:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-dependent-script.js"></script>
```

Everything works since the first script loads before the second one. But using Webpack:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="bundle.js"></script>
```

And in entries.js you have:

```
require('./jquery.js');
require('./jquery-dependent-script.js');
```

After compiling with `webpack ./entries.js bundle.js` the second script is going to fail due the Jquery/$ variable is not yet present. The loading is working because from the browser console I can see Jquery loaded. But at moment the second script is running it cannot find Jquery.

So, if I have a list of scripts to load, and some of them depends of others, how can I guarantee loading and executing of those is the first places?

Answer (score 0):

You need to utilize the [ProvidePlugin](https://webpack.github.io/docs/list-of-plugins.html#provideplugin).  This makes this module available anywhere it's called from code. (Basically whenever you need something on the global scope)

```
new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
    $: "jquery",
    jQuery: "jquery",
    "window.jQuery": "jquery"
})
```